# Clearing the input field after task is successful

Tags: fltk

I would like to clear the input field of my app when user clicks the save button and the input values are successfully saved.

Comment: do you want to clear it with Jquery?

Comment: 1) Does the form stay up for reuse or are you closing the form as well.  2) Does the save take a long time?  3) Is hiding the form or disabling the form an option?

Answer (score 1):

just use input->value(""); that´s all.